# How do you run private subs from a module?

Tags: vb.net, button, private-methods

I want to make a public sub in my module to to store a repeating procedure. Specifically key press events.

```
Private Sub txtPass_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) _
    Handles txtPass.KeyPress

    FunctionKeys(Me, sender, e)

End Sub

Public Sub  FunctionKeys(form as object, sender as object, _
    e as KeyPressEventArgs)

    With form
        If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then .btnOk_Click(sender, e)
        If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Escape) Then .btnClose_Click(sender, e)
    end with

End sub
```

I guess it would look something like this. Unfortunately, this tells me it can't find a public sub for formname.btnok_click etc. I want to know if there's a way around this. Looking around the net I found I can use the AcceptButton and CancelButton property. But only if i actually have a button to press. My MDI does not have buttons. Just menu. Also, I'm aware I can use formname.close() for the Keys.Escape. But I'd still have a problem with the OK button.

Comment: The event handler should not be private. It can call private methods within the same scope, but the event handler itself needs to be visible (protected or public)

Answer (score 0):

You can make `btnOk_Click` and `btnClose_Click` public on all your forms and that'll work.

Comment: Is there any drawback to this? I've thought about that actually but making a sub public might let me make the mistake of calling it somewhere else if i forget that i made it public. Any drawbacks aside from this?

Comment: Tell me something: should you call btnOk_Click from the outside for just one form? Or there are many forms that `FunctionKeys` can call btnOk_Click on them?

Comment: I don't think I'd have multiple forms accessible at one point. Right now most forms run at .ShowDialog(), making all forms inaccessible until I close the most recent one. Is this a problem?

Comment: Just make the methods public and you will be fine. Maybe better to give them new names. Just for clarification.

Comment: Guess that's worth a try. Thanks!